# rails server command show errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.2.15 and Ruby 2.3.1 on my Ubuntu system. Whenever I am trying to start server, I am getting these errors.

```
rails server

/var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270:
warning: circular argument reference - now
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.15 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

Unsupported version: 2.2.11

For more information, read the documentation:http://pat.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html

Exiting
/var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13) (Mysql2::Error)
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `initialize'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout' 
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection' 
  from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'  
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:310:in `clear_cache!'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.15/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__4005937425673360809__prepare__505669176022602409__callbacks'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  from /var/www/html/popthefizz.co.uk/releases/20131108040629/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require' 
  from /var/www/html/popthefizz.co.uk/releases/20131108040629/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  from /var/www/html/popthefizz.co.uk/releases/20131108040629/config.ru:in `new' 
  from /var/www/html/popthefizz.co.uk/releases/20131108040629/config.ru:in `<main>'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap' 
  from /var/www/vhosts/popthefizz.co.uk/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:7:in `require' 
  from script/rails:7:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I would try commenting out the socket in your db.yml in my experience you don't normally need it

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your gem file

```
gem 'riddle', '1.5.1' 
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.11', :require => "thinking_sphinx"
```

and run `bundle`